# OSX-like dictionary for Windows

Tags: windows, macos, software-rec, dictionary

Does anyone knows of an Apple OS X alike dictionary for Windows? No, I am not looking for WordWeb. I am looking for something very similar to the one on OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no dictionary for windows that closely resembles the OS X built-in dictionary tool. There are however a few which have similar functionality, but none that I know of that allows you to update the dictionary contents as you move the mouse across other words (which is a shame).

I'm unsure as to why you don't want WordWeb. But being that the case, you have other alternatives you may wish to explore.

A rather complete one is **[Everest Dictionary](http://www.free-soft.ro/everest/everest.html)**. Includes a Glossary, Translator and even Regular Expressions searching in addition to allowing you to get the meaning of a word by integrating with about any application displayed text, of course.

Comment: Right. I was afraid the answer would be so, nothing like it. WordWeb and the Everest you mention do not even get close to the inconspicuous OS X dictionary. I will accept this answer on the premises: "there is no dictionary for windows that closely resembles the OS X built-in dictionary tool"

Comment: I wish the answer was more satisfying. I too am a fan of OS X dictionary.

Comment: OSX's dictionary has an amazing UI. The app I use for Windows (called [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org)) is great, but OSX's dictionary, in fact its default apps in general, have an amazing UI.